# Export JSON data with image + testing POST method ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with a more architectural field. I'm doing a small project in ASP.NET MVC, which consists in adding advertisements by users. Currently, I'm already adding a new advertisement to the database. The next thing I want to work is to export the advertisement to an external server (which will be placed in the future). Here I have two issues that I can not solve.
First of all, how to export in the json format; description + photo? After doing the reserch, I tried using the POST method. I found 2 potential solutions. One method is using Ajax and the other is the POST method in the controller.

The second most important issue for me is how to test such a solution? It does not make a difference to me whether it is locally or online. I found the Postman tool. And here comes my main question. In the web-based tutorials in testing POST methods, they mainly focus on sending the POST method from the Postman tool (with manually entered data in the program)  and checking if the data has been saved in the database and sometimes on receiving the reqest. I care more about the testing and verifying the data sent from **my application** when adding a new advertisement (if format is corect and  the photo has been loaded) and presenting them on some mock server or another small project. 
I found the page http://ptsv2.com/ but I do not know if/how I can display data from the POST method on it.

Currently I add an advertisement by clicking a button that triggers an action in the controller:

```
<form class="form-horizontal vue-advertisement-form" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" action="@Url.Action("Create", "Advertisement")">
```

My export try looks like this:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSend').click(function() {
            var product = { Name: 'gfreelancer' }
            var jsonObjectTest = {
                "ID": "1525651",
                "Descriptiones": [{ "Price": "15$", "Description": "flat" }]
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:50097/ImportAdvertisementModels/Import",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonObjectTest),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
            });
        })
    });
    </script>
```

Which is probably not the best idea because in the sent data I also need data that is not in the form (eg customer's id). It's probably a better idea to send it from the controller, but I can not verify it and I do not know how the data was sent.

**So the most important question is how to test this export?**

Thank you for every answer or even the smallest clue

Comment: If you want to upload a file using ajax, then refer [How to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: thank you for your help @StephenMuecke, could you tell me how to test / display this data in an external application or project (not only in the controller of my project)?